# How to fix /usr/bin/env agrument processing?

Tags: linux, cluster-computing

I've run into a weird problem with */usr/bin/env*... I designed a simple script to show the problem. The script is in Ruby, but the same happens with a similar script in Python. Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

p ARGV
```

And another one without */usr/bin/env*:

```
#!/data/software/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby

p ARGV
```

As you see it should just print script arguments. An it works flawlessly on the head node:

```
[gusev@scyld test]$ which ruby
/data/software/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
[gusev@scyld test]$ ./script.no_usr_bin_env.rb 1 2 3
["1", "2", "3"]
[gusev@scyld test]$ ./script.usr_bin_env.rb 1 2 3
["1", "2", "3"]
```

But when running on computing node, it gets stuck:

```
[gusev@scyld test]$ qsub -d $(pwd) -I
qsub: waiting for job 176427.scyld.localdomain to start
qsub: job 176427.scyld.localdomain ready

-bash-3.2$ ./script.no_usr_bin_env.rb 1 2 3
["1", "2", "3"]
-bash-3.2$ ./script.usr_bin_env.rb 1 2 3
<stuck>
```

*/usr/bin/env* are exactly the same on both machines:

```
[gusev@scyld test]$ md5sum /usr/bin/env
7ada476000967f2e4cca2bc669045479  /usr/bin/env
[gusev@scyld test]$ qsub -I -d $(pwd)
qsub: waiting for job 176428.scyld.localdomain to start
qsub: job 176428.scyld.localdomain ready

-bash-3.2$ md5sum /usr/bin/env
7ada476000967f2e4cca2bc669045479  /usr/bin/env
```

I know that argument processing with */usr/bin/env* can be tricky. But we have a lot of software using this and we cannot just fix them all. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: are you sure that `ruby` in PATH on your node is any good? Is it identical to `/data/software/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby` ?

Comment: Indeed, the problem was with PATH variable on compute node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#!/usr/bin/env ruby` causes the script to be executed by the first `ruby` executable in `$PATH`. Your `$PATH` could be different on the compute node, most likely because of the way the environment is set up by `qsub`.

A quick and dirty fix would be:

```
PATH=/data/software/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:$PATH ./script.usr_bin_env.rb 1 2 3
```

but you should find a cleaner way to ensure that `$PATH` is set correctly before your Ruby scripts are executed.

For more detailed information, try `which ruby` or `type ruby` and `echo $PATH` on the compute node, and make sure that the `ruby` command actually works.

(For more discussion on `#!/usr/bin/env ...` vs. `#!.../ruby`, see [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454) to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454)).