# Super slow /usr/bin/env invocation

Tags: linux, cluster-computing

I am working on a computing cluster and I have a very weird /usr/bin/env behaviour... In two words, it works very slow.
On the head node:

```
$ time /usr/bin/env which
<which output>

real    0m0.025s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
```

On the computing node:

```
$ qsub -I                                                                                                                
qsub: waiting for job 176620.scyld.localdomain to start
qsub: job 176620.scyld.localdomain ready

-bash-3.2$ time which
<which output>

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.003s

-bash-3.2$ time /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/which

<which output>
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.003s


-bash-3.2$ time /usr/bin/env which
<which output>

real    5m0.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
```

*ps ax* reports this:

```
12884 pts/3    S+     0:00 /usr/bin/env which
```

It takes 5 min to print usage banner for which. Any ideas why this could happen?

**Edit 1:**

Additional info about which:

```
-bash-3.2$ type -a which
which is /usr/bin/which
-bash-3.2$ file /usr/bin/which
/usr/bin/which: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
-bash-3.2$ echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/bin:/home/gusev/.rvm/bin:/home/gusev/bin
```

**Edit 2**

I've `strace`'d `/usr/bin/env which` and it gets stuck at

```
execve("/bin/which", ["which"], [/* 47 vars */]
```

Now running a plain

```
/bin/which
```

also stucks, but this file does not exist:

```
-bash-3.2$ ls /bin/which
ls: /bin/which: No such file or directory
```

`/bin` is mounted over NFS:

```
-bash-3.2$ mount | grep bin
10.54.0.1:/bin on /bin type nfs (nolock,nonfatal)
10.54.0.1:/usr/bin on /usr/bin type nfs (nolock,nonfatal)
```

So this may be a networking issue...

**Edit 3:**

`which which` works perfectly fine:

```
-bash-3.2$ time which which
/usr/bin/which

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
```

The output of `strace -e trace=execve /usr/bin/env which` is

```
execve("/usr/bin/env", ["/usr/bin/env", "which"], [/* 47 vars */]) = 0
execve("/bin/which", ["which"], [/* 47 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/bin/which", ["which"], [/* 47 vars */]) = 0
<which output>
```

**Edit 4:**

The hang time is exactly 5 minutes always. Looks like it is some kind of default value timeout.

Comment: issue a "top" command, maybe there's some process eating your cputime

Comment: No, beostatus shows all 8 processors with 0% load.

Comment: Does `which which` suffer the same symptoms? Comparing `strace` output for `env which` and `which which`, env appears to be using `execve` to locate commands in each path in turn, which which uses `stat`.

Comment: BTW, what's the output for `strace -e trace=execve /usr/bin/env which`? In particular, what's the return code of the call `execve("/bin/which", ...)`?

Comment: `which which` is fine and `execve("/bin/which", ...)` returns `-1`...

Comment: Does your `/var/log/messages` have anything about disk issues? A failing disk can show as long access times for a while before it completely dies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found out that I have a very long `PATH` environment variable. And probable it somehow affected invoking `execve` of NFS share.

So I've moved a bunch of executables into a signle directory and replaces many entries in `PATH` with a single one. I do not expriencing any problems since then.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that it's the `which` command, not the `env` command, that's causing the problem.

Since you're seeing very different results for

```
time /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/which
```

vs.

```
time /usr/bin/env which
```

it's likely that you have another `which` command in your `$PATH`, perhaps in `/usr/local/bin` or `$HOME/bin`. What does `type -a which` tell you? What does your `$PATH` look like?

Note that `which` can be either a shell script or an executable. If it's a shell script, try grabbing a copy of it and adding `set -x` to see what it's doing.

Comment: I've updated my post... Basically which is just a plain executable. And it is the only one which in `$PATH`.

Comment: @user1179926: What happens when you invoke `which` directly?

Comment: it immediately outputs usage banner.

Answer (score 0):

This issue, as well as that described in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759588/how-to-fix-usr-bin-env-agrument-processing), appears to be caused by `execve` taking a long time to return on your compute notes. The fact that the dirs in your path are NFS mounted may be a contributing factor.

Running the commands through `strace`, we see that `env` uses repeated calls to `execve` to probed for the existence of the command in each path:

```
[me@home]$ echo $PATH
/home/me/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/me/work/bin

[me@home]$ strace -e execve /usr/bin/env which
execve("/usr/bin/env", ["/usr/bin/env", "which"], [/* 53 vars */]) = 0
execve("/home/me/bin/which", ["which"], [/* 53 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/which", ["which"], [/* 53 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/local/sbin/which", ["which"], [/* 53 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/local/bin/which", ["which"], [/* 53 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/sbin/which", ["which"], [/* 53 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/bin/which", ["which"], [/* 53 vars */]) = 0
```

As you have confirmed in the comments above, `which which` does not suffer the same issue and that's because it uses `stat` instead of `execve` to probe the paths:

```
[me@home]$ strace -e execve,stat /usr/bin/which which
execve("/usr/bin/which", ["/usr/bin/which", "which"], [/* 53 vars */]) = 0
stat("/home/me", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/me/bin/which", 0x7fff79ae8760) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/which", 0x7fff79ae8760) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/sbin/which", 0x7fff79ae8760) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/which", 0x7fff79ae8760) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/which", 0x7fff79ae8760) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/which", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=946, ...}) = 0
/usr/bin/which
```

I'm afraid cannot offer any suggestions to address the underlying problem, but in the mean-time you can work around the issue by:

1. Using full paths to commands instead of having `env` resolve them for you.
2. If you really wish to use `env`, whenever possible reorder your `$PATH` to minimise the search. E.g.:

   ```
   PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH /usr/bin/env which   # place most likely path first
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Unfortunately, the problem with `env` was just a tip of the iceberg: i have a lot of software running into this problem and I cannot fix all of that.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like an issue you need to take up with your sysadmin. Are the other cases suffering from the same symptoms?

Comment: The problem is: I am the sysadmin. I noticed the problem when some (not all) software suddenly just hanged in there, spending no CPU cycles for days. After analysis I boiled the problem down to the one described in the post.

Comment: Oh dear. Sorry I can't be of more help. Good luck.